# Hibernate Search cannot set default tokenizer

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

i have created a custom analyzer, which I want to be now the default one.
My analyzer looks like:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name="customanalyzer",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
})
```

and it works great. But I must write on each entity

```
@Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
```

which I don't want to.

So I tried to put my analyzer into my application.yml
It works perfectly for the filter but not for the tokenizer

My application.yml looks like:

```
spring:
  ...
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ...
    properties:
      hibernate:
        search:
          default:
            directory_provider: filesystem
            indexBase: [removed]
          analyzer:
            tokenizer: WhitespaceTokenizerFactory   <-- this line is not working
            filter: LowerCaseFilterFactory
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default analyzer for all your entities using the configuration property:

```
hibernate.search.analyzer=customanalyzer
```

Comment: True. You cannot define tokenizers/filters/etc. in your configuration properties, only reference an existing analyzer definition ("customanalyzer" in your case) or an analyzer implementation ("org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer" for instance).